# Vendor systems returned INVALID or ERROR in response to notification POST - Sagepay Server

Tags: opayo, opencart2.x

Ive built 2 websites using opencart 2 (many more on Opencart 1) and both are setup to take Sagepay Server payments, But its now come to light that both sites Sagepay payments are failing when Sagepay tries to talk back to opencart to give the green light. This means no failure email notification is sent to the store owner, and the sale is cancelled at Sagepay? as you can imagine both store owners are not happy. I contacted Sagepay to see what was happening and they told me the payments were failing with the below Error, but as far as Sagepay was concerned the payments had passed all tests, but because the calling website could not send the correct response back to Sagepay, they had to cancel the transactions!

Looking at how Sagepay works, it seams sagepay returns autorisation to Opencart and then opencart has to say whether its going to accept the payment based upon what is being sent, and it seams this is where opencart 2 is failing to respond correctly?

Is this yet another OC2 bug?

Has anyone come across this and how do I put this right

One site is on OC 2.0.2.0 and the other one is 2.0.3.1
Everything is setup correctly in payment module and IP Address logged with sagepay etc.., its just a problem after payment authorisation.

> Transaction completed but Vendor systems returned INVALID or ERROR in
>   response to notification POST. Transaction CANCELLED by the Vendor.

This is a really big problem, and not sure how to go about fixing this, as Opencart 2 is meant to be able to take sagepay payments out of the box, once a few settings are added in the admin section, but it seams its not setup correctly to do so.. I cant believe no one else has come across this?

Comment: This could be due to a mismatch in the signature values - Opencart could then be rejecting the transaction. There are some extra fields which are returned in protocol 3 - might be worth checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the built in sage pay debug option which told me it was a MD5 Hash mismatch, after further digging and reading the official Sage pay Server docs, there was a notice in Bold Red, stating to ensure the Vendor name was supplied all in lower case, mine was in title case in the admin section. It looks like the creator of Opencart 2 has over looked this, I simply used php`s strtolower function before the MD5 comparison in the sagepay_server.php controller file to convert the vendor name to lowercase. Of course this could be avoided by entering the vendor name in the sage pay server admin section as lower case. But seeing as there is no note when entering this, opencart should convert the vendor name to lowercase as I have done to ensure no possibility of this error.